# Exception self.context.XXX.subscribe is not a function

Tags: angular, angular2-components

In my Angular 2 app I need to pass an array from one component to another one. I have a component named `SystemDynamicsComponent` that exposes one array `sdFactors`:

```
@Component({
   selector: "system-dynamics",
   templateUrl: "/app/component/main/template/system-dynamics.html"
})

export class SystemDynamicsComponent implements OnInit {
    private dialogDisplayed: boolean = false;
   @Output() sdFactors: any[] = [];
```

In the component named `InputModuleComponent` I need to read this value as follows:

Template:

```
<system-dynamics (sdFactors)="this.sdFactors"></system-dynamics>
```

Component:

```
export class InputModuleComponent implements OnInit {
...
sdFactors: any[] = [];
```

When launchig the input module component, I receive this error message from Angular:
`TypeError: self.context.sdFactors.subscribe is not a function
    at Wrapper_SystemDynamicsComponent.subscribe (wrapper.ngfactory.js:38)
    at View_InputModuleComponent6.createInternal (component.ngfactory.js:3103)
    at View_InputModuleComponent6.AppView.create (core.umd.js:12262)
    at View_InputModuleComponent6.DebugAppView.create (core.umd.js:12666)
    at TemplateRef_.createEmbeddedView (core.umd.js:9320)
    at ViewContainerRef_.createEmbeddedView (core.umd.js:9552)`

Any ideas what I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<system-dynamics (sdFactors)="sdFactors"></system-dynamics>
```

instead of

```
<system-dynamics (sdFactors)="this.sdFactors"></system-dynamics>
```

you dont need to add `this` in the template for binding. Variables from the same class can be accessed without `this` in the template.

## Update

`@output` is used for event binding not for property binding , you have to use `@input` for passign array or some variable value so use this like this

```
<system-dynamics [sdFactors]="sdFactors"></system-dynamics>
```

and in you component like this

```
@Component({
   selector: "system-dynamics",
   templateUrl: "/app/component/main/template/system-dynamics.html"
})

export class SystemDynamicsComponent implements OnInit {
    private dialogDisplayed: boolean = false;
   @Input() sdFactors: any[] = [];
```

Comment: I changed it like you proposed (`<system-dynamics (sdFactors)="sdFactors"></system-dynamics>`), however the issue remains.

Comment: please see my Update